# How do I integrate $\int{\frac{2\sin{x}-x\cos{x}}{2 \sqrt{ \sin{x}}\sin{x}}dx}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

> How do I integrate $\int{\frac{2\sin{x}-x\cos{x}}{2 \sqrt{ \sin{x}}\sin{x}}dx}$?

My try:

$$\int{\frac{2 \sin{x} -x \cos{x}}{2 \sqrt{\sin{x}}\sin{x}}}dx=\int{\frac{\sqrt{ \sin{x}} -\frac{x \cos{x}}{2\sqrt{ \sin{x}}}}{\sin{x}}}dx=\int\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\right)^{'}dx=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}+C.$$

But is there simpler way?

I mean that the method used above, how can mind come to it?

Comment: Simpler than magically deducing the result?

Comment: yes, exactly , I appreciate any help or suggestion from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I mean, this seems like the simplest way there is (realizing the integrand is the derivative of some function). You'd prolly see such by just exploring the integrand in general, and in this particular case, reduce the denominator down to just the sine.

Here's an alternative method that I probably would approach with that is slightly more tedious but works
$$\frac{2 \sin{x} -x \cos{x}}{2 \sqrt{\sin{x}}\sin{x}} = \frac12\cdot\frac{2\sin x - x\cos x}{\sin^{3/2}x}$$
$$\implies \frac12\int\frac{2\sin x}{\sin^{3/2}x} - \frac{ x\cos x}{\sin^{3/2}x}\text{ d}x = {\color{red}{\int\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}}} - {\color{blue}{\frac12\int\frac{x\cot x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\text{ d}x}}$$
Integrating the blue integral by parts with $u=x$ (derivative) and $v=\frac{\cot x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}$ (integral), we can see that with $u=\frac1{\sqrt{\sin x}}$ our $v$ integral is easily solvable.

Hence we have
$${\color{red}{\int\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}}} - \frac12\left({\color{blue}{x\cdot\frac{-2}{\sqrt{\sin x}}-\int\frac{-2}{\sqrt{\sin x}}\text{ d}x}}\right)$$
$${\color{red}{\int\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}}}+ {\color{blue}{x\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin x}}-\int\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}}} $$
$$\implies \boxed{\frac{x}{\sqrt{\sin x}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

One way is push through with IBP:

Let $u' = 2\sin{x} - x\cos{x} \\ v = \dfrac{1}{2\sin^{3/2}{x}}$

See that $(x\cos{x})' = \cos{x} - x\sin{x} \\ (x\cos{x})'' = -2\sin{x} - x\cos{x}$

$$\therefore \int{u'} = \int{2\sin{x}} \space \mathrm{dx} - \int{x\cos{x}} \space \mathrm{dx} = \int{2\sin{x}} \space \mathrm{dx} + \left(\int{(x\cos{x})''} \space \mathrm{dx} + \int{2\sin{x}} \space \mathrm{dx} \right) \\= -3\cos{x} - x\sin{x}$$

Hence,

$$\int{\dfrac{2\sin{x} - x\cos{x}}{2\sin^{3/2}{x}}} \space \mathrm{dx} \quad \xrightarrow{\normalsize{\text{IBP}}} \quad \dfrac{-3\cos{x} - x\sin{x}}{2\sin^{3/2}{x}} - \underbrace{\int{\dfrac{3\cos{x} \cdot (3\cos{x} + x\sin{x})}{4\sin^{5/2}{x}}} \space \mathrm{dx}}_{\displaystyle{\color{blue}{\dfrac{9}{4}\int{\cos{x} \cdot \dfrac{\cos{x}}{\sin^{5/2}{x}}} \space \mathrm{dx}} + \color{red}{\dfrac{3}{4}\int{x \cdot \dfrac{1}{\sin^{3/2}{x}}} \space \mathrm{dx}} }} $$

---

$$\color{blue}{\dfrac{9}{4}\int{\cos{x} \cdot \dfrac{\cos{x}}{\sin^{5/2}{x}}} \space \mathrm{dx}} \quad \xrightarrow{\normalsize{\text{IBP}}} \quad 
-\dfrac{3\cos{x}}{2\sin^{3/2}{x}} - \dfrac{3}{2}\int{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}\space \mathrm{dx}}$$

$$\color{red}{\dfrac{3}{4}\int{x \cdot \dfrac{1}{\sin^{3/2}{x}}} \space \mathrm{dx}} \quad \xrightarrow{\normalsize{\text{IBP}}} \quad \dfrac{-3x}{2\sqrt{\sin{x}}} + \dfrac{3}{2}\int{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}\space \mathrm{dx}}$$

---

$$\require{\cancel}{\therefore \color{blue}{\dfrac{9}{4}\int{\cos{x} \cdot \dfrac{\cos{x}}{\sin^{5/2}{x}}} \space \mathrm{dx}} + \color{red}{\dfrac{3}{4}\int{x \cdot \dfrac{1}{\sin^{3/2}{x}}} \space \mathrm{dx}} \\= -\dfrac{3\cos{x}}{2\sin^{3/2}{x}} - \xcancel{\dfrac{3}{2}\int{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}\space \mathrm{dx}}} + \dfrac{-3x}{2\sqrt{\sin{x}}} + \xcancel{\dfrac{3}{2}\int{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}}\space \mathrm{dx}}}} \\= -\left(\dfrac{3\cos{x}}{2\sin^{3/2}{x}} + \dfrac{3x}{2\sqrt{\sin{x}}}\right)$$

---

Finally,

$$\int{\dfrac{2\sin{x} - x\cos{x}}{2\sin^{3/2}{x}}} \space \mathrm{dx} \quad \xrightarrow{\normalsize{\text{IBP}}} \quad -\dfrac{3\cos{x}}{2\sin^{3/2}{x}} - \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}} + \dfrac{3\cos{x}}{2\sin^{3/2}{x}} + \dfrac{3x}{2\sqrt{\sin{x}}} + C$$

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{\sin{x}}} + C}$$